# AWS Lambda Function Test Failure

Tags: node.js, xml, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda

I tried to run test(s) several times on the AWS Lambda, but i am getting this error even i have look through the code thoroughly and could not come up with a solution that solves this issue.

If anyone who was prior knowledge of XML data processing, any solutions are welcome.

This is the error, i am getting:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Input buffer has corrupt header: glib: XML parse error: Error domain 1 code 5 on line 24 column 15 of data: Extra content at the end of the document",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Input buffer has corrupt header: glib: XML parse error: Error domain 1 code 5 on line 24 column 15 of data: Extra content at the end of the document"
  ]
}
```

Source Code:

```
    // AWS packages
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// Image processing packages
const sharp = require("sharp");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Function to update the DynomoDb table
async function updateDynomoDBObject() {
  const quoteTableName = process.env.API_QUOTEGEN_QUOTEAPPTESTTABLE_NAME;
  const quoteObejectID = "Object ID goes here";

  try {
    var quoteParams = {
      TableName: quoteTableName,
      Key: {
        id: quoteObejectID,
      },
      UpdateExpression: "SET #quotesGenerated = #quotesGenerated + :inc",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":inc": 1,
      },
      ExpressionAtributeNames: {
        "#quotesGenerated": "quotesGenerated",
      },
      ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
    };
    const updateQuoteObject = await docClient.update(quoteParams).promise();
    return updateQuoteObject;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      "Error is catched in updating the quote object in DynomoDB",
      error
    );
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const apiURL = "https://zenquotes.io/api/random";

  // Generate a quote image using sharp

  async function getRandomQuote(apiURLInput) {
    // my quote is ..
    let quoteText;
    // author name here
    let quoteAuthor;

    // validate response to the api
    const response = await fetch(apiURLInput);
    var quoteData = await response.json();
    console.log(quoteData);

    // quote elements
    quoteText = quoteData[0].q;
    quoteAuthor = quoteData[0].a;

    // image construction
    const width = 750;
    const height = 483;
    const text = quoteText;
    const words = text.split(" ");
    const lineBreak = 4;
    let newText = "";

    // define some tspan elements 4 words each
    let tspanElements = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      newText += words[i] + " ";
      if ((i + 1) % lineBreak === 0) {
        tspanElements += `<tspan x="${
          width / 2
        }" dy="1.2em">${newText}</tspan>`;
        newText = "";
      }
    }
    if (newText !== "") {
      tspanElements += `<tspan x="${width / 2}" dy="1.2em">${newText}</tspan>`;
    }
    console.log(tspanElements);

    // construct SVG
    const svgImg = `
      <svg width="${width}" height="${height}">
          <style>
            .title {
                fill: #ffffff;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }     
            .quoteAuthorStyles {
                font-size: 35px;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 50px;
            }
            .footerStyles {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                fill: lightgrey;
                text-anchor: middle;
                font-family: Verdana;
            }
            </style>
            <circle cx="382" cy="76" r="44" fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.155)"/>
            <text x="382" y="76" dy="50" text-anchor="middle" font-size="90" font-family="Verdana" fill=""white">"</text>
            <g>
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="${width}" height="auto"></rect>
                <text id="lastLineOfQuote" x="375" y="120" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="white" text-anchor="middle"> 
                    <tspan x="${width / 2}" dy="1.2em">${tspanElements}</tspan>
                    <tspan class="quoteAuthorStyles" x="375" dy="1.8em">-${quoteAuthor}</tspan>          
                </text>
            </g>
            <text x="${width / 2}" y="${
      height - 10
    }" class="footerStyles"> Developed by @Sardor-M | Quotes from ZenQuotes.io</text>
    </svg>
    `;

    // add background images for the svg creation
    const backgroundImages = [
      "backgrounds/Delhi.png",
      "backgrounds/DeepSea.png",
      "backgrounds/Dusk.png",
      "backgrounds/Sun.png",
    ];

    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgroundImages.length);
    const selectedBackgoundImage = backgroundImages[randomIndex];

    // Composite this image together
    const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
    const svgBuffer = Buffer.from(svgImg);

    const imagePath = path.join("/tmp", "quote-card.png");
    const image = await sharp(selectedBackgoundImage)
      .composite([
        {
          input: svgBuffer,
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
        },
      ])
      .toFile(imagePath);

    // function to update the quote object in DynomoDB
    try {
      updateDynomoDBObject();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error in updating the quote object in DynomoDB", error);
    }
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      //  Uncomment below to enable CORS requests
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      },
      body: fs.readFileSync(imagePath).toString("base64"),
      isBase64Encoded: true,
    };
  }
  return await getRandomQuote(apiURL);
};
```

I have checked the API endpoints and the response i am getting. However i could not see the problem .

Comment: The issue seems to be in an XML document you're parsing. There isn't much we can do without seeing that :-)

Comment: I will share the source code in a minute ~

Comment: Code looks like it is using JSON which is not XML.  Where is the XML?  Document may require XML or you may need to set the document type to JSON.  Here is your document : docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();  Looks like it is JSON : AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient

Comment: I'm guessing something is complaining about the SVG which is an XML document.

Comment: Looks like the STYLE in the SVG is JSON and not XML.  Where is you get the Style?

Comment: @Maurice Yeah, i thought the same thing, SVG is becoming  a problem here.